# mle2 function: L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain power of likelihood ratio test for comparing gamma distribution against generalized gamma distribution. And so I need maximum likelihood estimates of Generalized gamma distribution with three parameters. I wrote code as follows.

```
library(bbmle)
library(flexsurv)

sig=0.05
den=1000

n=30
apar=2 ###alfa
bpar=3 ##beta
cpar=4 ##c parametresi

LRatio=function(den,n,par=c(cpar,apar,bpar)){

  LR2=rep(0,den)

  count=rep(0,den)

  cpar=par[1]
  apar=par[2]
  bpar=par[3]

  for(i in 1:den){

    y=rgengamma.orig(n,shape=cpar,scale=bpar,k=apar)

    gamma4 = function(shape, scale) {
      -sum(dgamma(y, shape = shape, scale = scale,log = TRUE))
    }

    gm = mean(y)
    cv = var(y)/mean(y)


    m5 = mle2(gamma4, start = list(shape = gm/cv, scale = cv),method = "L-BFGS-B", lower =c(.00001,.00001),upper = c(Inf,Inf))

    gengamma3 = function(shape, scale,k) {
      -sum(dgengamma.orig(y, shape = shape, scale = scale,k=k,log =TRUE))
      #-(n*log(abs(shape))-n*shape*k*log(scale)+(shape*k-1)*sum(log(y))-n*log(exp(lgamma(k)))-sum((y/scale)^shape))
    }


    ci=mean(y)            #c initial value
    a1=ci*mean(y)^(ci-1)
    a2=ci*(ci-1)*(mean(y)^(ci-1))/2
    mu1=mean(y)^ci+a2*mean(y^2)
    mu2=(a1^2)*mean(y^2)+2*a1*a2*mean(y^3)+(a2^2)*(mean(y^4)-mean(y^2)^2)
    alp =(mu1^2)/mu2                            #alpha initial value
    bet=mean(y)*gamma(alp)/gamma(alp+(1/ci))       #beta initial value


    m6 = mle2(gengamma3,start = list(shape = ci, scale = bet, k=alp),method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0,0),upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf))

    LR2[i]=2*(logLik(m6)-logLik(m5))
    count[i]=LR2[i]>=qchisq(1-sig, df=1) 

  }

  pow=sum(count)/den
  print(i)
  print(pow)
}
```

But I got error :

```
optim(par = c(3.88907163215354, 3.62005456122935, 1.66499331462506 :
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I am guessing that`gamma4` and  `gengamma3` are divergent for some of the parameters in the search space. You can troubleshoot this by restricting the search space by varying the lower and upper bounds (which are absurdly wide at the moment).

Comment: Also note all the warnings you get when you run this because of "value out of range in `lgamma`. Get rid of these first before you continue.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-November/433845.html

Comment: In the gengamma3, it is used generalized gamma distribution. I know in the simulation some values are not suitable for lgamma. But how can I get rid of these values?